# Selecting the first non-zero value from each column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a 10x100 data frame called `CoeNIST`. The rows are in order of significance (i.e. the value in row 1 is more important than the value in row 2) and each column represents a different sample. I would like to extract only the most significant non-zero value, i.e. the first non-zero value, for each sample.

Here is a sample from the first 9 columns of `CoeNIST`.

```
>  CoeNIST[,1:9]
         1      2      3      4 5 6 7      8 9
1       0 352232      0      0 0 0 0  28733 0
2  332829      0      0 380109 0 0 0 380343 0
3       0      0      0 380111 0 0 0 380409 0
4       0      0      0 380101 0 0 0      0 0
5       0      0 299211 380112 0 0 0      0 0
6       0      0      0 380103 0 0 0      0 0
7       0      0      0 380100 0 0 0  71899 0
8       0      0      0  24812 0 0 0      0 0
9       0      0      0      0 0 0 0 380410 0
10      0 332958      0      0 0 0 0 380440 0
```

And here is what I would like the outcome to look like

```
>  NIST
[1] 332829 352232 299211 380109 NA NA NA 28733 NA
```

OR...as a list...

```
>  NIST
[[1]] 
[1] 332829 

[[2]] 
[1] 352232 

[[3]] 
[1] 299211 

[[4]] 
[1] 380109 

[[5]] integer(0)

[[6]] integer(0)

[[7]] integer(0) 

[[8]] 
[1] 28733 

[[9]] integer(0)
```

Comment: "The rows are in order of signifigance and the columns are each sample. I would like to extract only the most signifigant value for each sample." -- wouldn't this mean just selecting the top row, if the rows are in order of significance?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by _most significant_. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @ Johnnyboy, It would if all of the top rows had values, If the column has a value i would like to extract it. Therefore, if there is a value in the ninth row, and all zeros above it, i would like to take the value from the ninth row.

Comment: That's still not clear. For column 4 you have multiple non-zero values. How/why did you choose '380109' vs another value?

Comment: OP wants the *first* non-zero value in the column, apparently ...

Comment: Because 380109 is in row 2, the highest row number with a nonzero value,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CoeNIST <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
1      2      3      4 5 6 7      8 9
1       0 352232      0      0 0 0 0  28733 0
2  332829      0      0 380109 0 0 0 380343 0
3       0      0      0 380111 0 0 0 380409 0
4       0      0      0 380101 0 0 0      0 0
5       0      0 299211 380112 0 0 0      0 0
6       0      0      0 380103 0 0 0      0 0
7       0      0      0 380100 0 0 0  71899 0
8       0      0      0  24812 0 0 0      0 0
9       0      0      0      0 0 0 0 380410 0
10      0 332958      0      0 0 0 0 380440 0")
```

I would describe your problem as "selecting the first non-zero value in each column." My solution gives you `NA` values when there are only zeros in the column ...

```
apply(CoeNIST,2,function(x) (x[x>0])[1])
##     X1     X2     X3     X4     X5     X6     X7     X8     X9 
## 332829 352232 299211 380109     NA     NA     NA  28733     NA
```

Comment: Thank You. Sorry for any confusion in the way I asked the question.

Comment: No problem - just try to take whatever you can from the exchange of comments that will help you ask better questions in the future. (Giving a reproducible example and the desired output, as you did, is really good because it helps answerers guess what you mean when you've been unable to describe your question clearly ...)

Comment: (since you're editing your question, consider retitling it something like "extracting first non-zero element from each column of a data frame" ...)

Comment: Why would you use `apply` on a `data.frame`? Isn't it both more efficient and safer to use `sapply` or `lapply` (matrix conversions)?

Comment: I can imagine efficiency and safety differences, but I don't recall encountering any issues with using `apply` on data frames in my day-to-day analysis (I generally work with small- to medium-size data sets; OP's data set is quite small)

Comment: What theoretical example of misleading results could be `apply(iris, 2, class)`. But there could me many worse

Answer (score 1):

```
CoeNIST = matrix(c(0, 352232, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28733, 0, 332829, 0, 0, 380109, 0, 0, 0, 380343, 0, 0, 0, 0, 380111, 0, 0, 0, 380409, 0, 0, 0, 0, 380101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 299211, 380112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 380103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 380100, 0, 0, 0, 71899, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24812, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 380410, 0, 0, 332958, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 380440, 0), nrow=10, ncol=10, byrow=T)

> CoeNIST
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3] [,4] [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]
 [1,]      0 352232      0    0    0      0      0  28733      0 332829
 [2,]      0      0 380109    0    0      0 380343      0      0      0
 [3,]      0 380111      0    0    0 380409      0      0      0      0
 [4,] 380101      0      0    0    0      0      0      0 299211 380112
 [5,]      0      0      0    0    0      0      0      0 380103      0
 [6,]      0      0      0    0    0      0      0 380100      0      0
 [7,]      0  71899      0    0    0      0  24812      0      0      0
 [8,]      0      0      0    0    0      0      0      0      0 380410
 [9,]      0      0 332958    0    0      0      0      0 380440      0
[10,]      0 352232      0    0    0      0      0  28733      0 332829
```

This is for the max of each column:

```
apply(CoeNIST, 2, function(x){x_max = max(x); if(x_max == 0) NULL else x_max})})
```

This is for the first non-zero value in a column:

```
apply(CoeNIST, 2, function(x){x_top_non_zero = min(which(x>0)); if(x_top_non_zero == Inf) {NaN} else {x_top_non_zero}} )
```

Comment: I'm not looking for the maximum numeric value, i'm looking for the value that exists in the highest row.

Comment: @ZachEisner, are you then seeking the first non-zero value in each row?